# include search in header bootsrap and angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the below code to include search in header but unable to align properly based on the length

i want the search to be aligned like below
[image]

so, if i add a new menu to the header then it should automatically adjustin the space available.

Now, it is appearing like below

[image]

```
<div>
  <nav class="navbar-inverse" ng-class="::{'navbar':!isViewNative, 'is-native': isViewNative}"
       role="navigation">
    <div ng-show="::!isViewNative" class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand"  href="#"><span>Test</span></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand navbar-brand-logo"href="#">
        <img ng-src="something" />
      </a>

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#he-nav-bar">
        <span class="sr-only">${Toggle navigation}</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>


    <div sp-navbar-toggle="" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="he-nav-bar">
  /**added search here**********/
<form method="get" action="?">
  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="search"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="t" value="{{data.searchType}}"/>
  <div class="input-group input-group-{{::c.options.size}}">
    <!-- uses ui.bootstrap.typeahead -->
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="{{::c.options.title}}" ng-model="c.selectedState"
           ng-model-options="{debounce: 250}" autocomplete="off"
           uib-typeahead="item as item.label for item in c.getResults($viewValue)"
           typeahead-focus-first="false"
           typeahead-on-select="c.onSelect($item, $model, $label)"
           typeahead-template-url="sp-typeahead.html" class="form-control input-typeahead">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button name="search" type="submit" class="btn btn-{{::c.options.color}}">
        <i ng-if="::c.options.glyph" class="fa fa-{{::c.options.glyph}}"></i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
      <ul ng-if="" class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href ng-click="openLogin()">${Login}</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul ng-if="" class="nav navbar-nav">        
        <li ng-if="><a href ng-click="openPopUp()">${Help}</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown hidden-xs">
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a ng-href="">${menu}</a></li>
            <li><a href="">${submenu}</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="visible-xs-block"><a ng-href=""><span class="navbar-avatar"><sn-avatar class="avatar-small-medium" /></span>${name}</a></li>
        <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="">${Logout}</a></li>
      </ul> 
    </div>

  </nav>  
</div>
```

Thanks and regards,
Krishna

Comment: If possible please create a plunkr, it will take few minutes and easier for us to play around and give a fix.

Comment: Hi Jha, Thanks for your reply. I pasted the code in below https://plnkr.co/edit/GH6Pogkd8LBbETfZRFtm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this will work for you
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/wPW3AoWvLm37Lz29Pq2Z?p=preview